# Installing Wordpress in Subdirectory/Folder

Tags: wordpress, directory, subdirectory

I'm just putting a couple of Wordpress sites live that are installed in a folder (not the root dir) on the server - e.g. `/wordpress/`

My question is this - the Wordpress codex suggests doing this for security reasons and then resetting permalinks, with the `index.php` file on the root of the server. I however am using `home.php` as a static front page so it seems this may not work. As I'm manually putting in the navigation links onto this page (which I suppose necessarily must include e.g `/wordpress/` in their path) does that not invalidate the security rationale behind installing in a folder?

Alternatively should I update all of the permalinks anyway, ignore index.php and just point to where the pages are supposedly situated?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress permalinking works in relation to the install folder, no matter where that is as far as I know. I've installed it in both a root level and sub-folder and never had any problems.

Have you got specific domains you're using with these sites? As long as those domains point to the correct folder you should be fine.

Also, your home.php home page - why are you using this rather than a Wordpress page/post?

Comment: I'm using the home.php page mainly for the sake of customisation - a little bit more freedom than your usual static front page. My question is I guess more about the security implications - I can get all of the paths working via either method, but is the reason for a subdirectory install that a reader cannot see exactly where the files are actually located?